# Create a two column layout that fits to content with Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a two column layout. Column 1 is a heading. Column 2 is a list.

I want the columns to fit to content. (e.g. Column 1 should be as wide as it's contents)

I also want the list to be horizontal.

I want to use Flexbox, so I can change items in the list and have the layout adapt accordingly.

E.g. So it looks like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Here is my code **([Codepen is here](http://codepen.io/madhusharma/pen/qdOWyZ))**:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<nav class="topics"> 
<span class="unit unit-header">Topics: </span>
<ul id="list" class="list unit">
  <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Topic 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Topic 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Topic 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Topic 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Topic 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Topic 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</div>

.wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top:20px;
}

.topics {
  display: flex;
}

.unit {
  flex: 1 auto;
}

.list {
  display:flex;  
}

.list li {
  flex: 1 auto;
}
```

If I add the following code, it works:

```
.unit-header {
  display: table;
  padding-right: 5%;
}
```

However, mixing table with flex-box seems a bit hacky to me. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using this instead?

```
.unit-header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

The above shorthand property means:

> flex-grow: 0
>
> flex-shrink: 1
>
> flex-basis: auto

Comment: That works but then the links are bunched together. How can I get the links to space out evenly, while keeping the header column fit to its contents?

Comment: @big_smile Are you looking for [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) or simply like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJebNp

Comment: Yup, justify-content worked! So the code is `.list {justify-content: space-around;}`

Comment: @big_smile cool, well `space-between` might be even better in the case - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpaOrj it's totally up to you :)